# Getting error undefined : math in go lang when using math/rand library

Tags: go

When I run the following code it gives the error undefined math in the line

```
fmt.Println("The square root of 4 is",math.Sqrt(4))
```

However when i run only one method (foo or boo) no error is given.

```
package main 

    import ("fmt"
           "math/rand")

    func main() {
        boo();
        foo();

    }

    func boo()  {
        fmt.Println("A number from 1-100",rand.Intn(100))
    }
    func foo() {

        fmt.Println("The square root of 4 is",math.Sqrt(4))
    }
```

Comment: Importing "math/rand" imports just "math/rand" and _not_ "math" too. If you want to import package math you must do `import "math"`.

Comment: this would prevent running foo() alone, wouldn't it? He claims foo() alone does run - maybe your IDE (if you use one) auto corrects the imports when you make changes?

Comment: @Volker This is an answer; you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

As Volker said in the comments, importing `math/rand` does not import `math`. You have to `import "math"` explicitely.

Go is not an interpreted language. Imports are resolved at compile time, not at runtime. It doesn't matter which of the two functions you call, or even if you don't call any of them. The code doesn't compile either way:

```
$ nl -ba main.go 
 1  package main
 2
 3  import (
 4          "fmt"
 5          "math/rand"
 6  )
 7
 8  func main() {
 9  }
10
11  func boo() {
12          fmt.Println("A number from 1-100", rand.Intn(100))
13  }
14  func foo() {
15          fmt.Println("The square root of 4 is", math.Sqrt(4))
16  }
$ go build
# _/tmp/tmp.doCnt09SnR
./main.go:15:48: undefined: math
```

Comment: import path refers to directory name, I am confused to see "math/rand" as import path. Does it mean package file that belong to rand are in subdirectory of math or it means all rand package files have package name "math/rand"

Comment: @Tarun, you can see the code for the standard library at https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src. It is important to not confuse import paths with package names. The package name is "rand" and its import path is "math/rand" because its source code is located in GOROOT/src/math/rand (GOROOT/src is the root directory for the standard library, linked above).